# Can I use official apns (or easy apns) with the push notification?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, trigger.io, forge, parse-platform

I want to use easy apns with the iphone app, but I don't know whether can use apns with forge(don't use Parse service), I cannot found any APIs for this, and within phoneGap, I can edit the native objective-c code to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, we don't support interfacing with APNS directly: we'd be really interested to hear why Parse's offering isn't suitable for you?

We were originally planning on offering some other 3rd party push integration before raw APNS, but happy to revise that plan if we're missing some key insight.

Comment: cause with parse or other 3rd party push service (like Urban Airship) are not totally free(not enought with free plan), and with our client, they have a server for this, so just want to use the offical apns service with ower server.

Comment: Using the official APN would be more ideal.  Also, how does Parse handle push notifications -- it appears that for iPhone they use the APN; isn't receiving the push notification the same whether it came from parse's servers or others?

Comment: Alex is right. Push is delivered by APNS regardless of which platform you use. You do need to at least be able to override the didRegisterForRemoteNotifications: method, in order to submit the deviceToken to your provider.

Comment: I'm as well interested in using APNS directly, since we have a backend service which is integrated into the CMS to push notifications and don't need any third-party tools. Would be awesome, if you can bring forward raw APNS instead of other services.